# Match functions with more than two arguments with Regex

Tags: python, regex, pcre, parentheses

I want to write a regular expression in Python that matches functions with more than two arguments, such that the following expressions match:

```
function(1, 2, 3)
function(1, 2, 3, 4)
function(1, function(1, 2), 3)
function(function(function(1, 2), 2), 2, 3, 4)
```

but the following don't:

```
function(1, 2)
function(1, function(1, function(1, 2)))
function(1, function(function(1), 2))
```

My best attempt was the following expression, which only works for the cases without nested functions:

```
\w+\((?:.*,){2,}.*\)
```

What expression should I use instead?

Comment: Looks like a parser would be a better tool

Comment: Please clarify the question. Do you mean "two or more" or do you mean "more than two"? The words in the opening sentance do not match the examples that should not match.

Comment: Why shouldn't `function(1, 2)` and `function(1, function(1, function(1, 2)))` match? As far as I can see, each of the functions has 2 arguments.

Comment: Do you mean "two integer aguments"?

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to try/do this with regex. What is your actual use case or requirement? Why do you need to parse function call?

Comment: At least Python's `re` module of the standard library doesn't support arbitrary nesting.

Comment: @AdrianHHH I apologize, I mistyped it. I meant more than two. It's corrected now.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride I have a pandas dataframe with a bunch of expressions like those. I'd like to delete the rows that have functions calls with more than two arguments

Comment: Just to show how horrible a regex that finds function calls which have at least two integer arguments would be (I know this is not the question), I'm placing [this link](https://regex101.com/r/7ferG6/1) here. If you are unintimidated, perhaps you can continue from there. Otherwise, play safe and write a parser.

Answer (score 0):

For fun, you can recursively [`sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)/replace the right-most functions with a placeholder (*e.g, a hyphen*) and only in the end, [`count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) the remaining arguments in each expression :

```
import re

MIN_ARGS = 3

#https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names
pyfunc = r"\b[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*"

pat = fr"({pyfunc}\(.*)(?:{pyfunc})?({pyfunc}\(.+?\))(.+)"

def fn(s):
    if len(re.findall(pyfunc, s)) > 1:
        new_s = re.sub(pat, r"\1-\3", s)
        return fn(new_s)
    else:
        return s
```

> Regex : [[*demo - first iteration*](https://regex101.com/r/YvmWqM/1)]

Output :

```
# `text` is the multistring holding your expressions

for exp in text.splitlines():
    if (n:=fn(exp).count(",")) > MIN_ARGS-2:
        print(f"{exp:<50}", n+1, f"{'MATCH':>10}")
    else:
        print(f"{exp:<50}", n+1, f"{'NO-MATCH':>10}")

function(1, 2, 3)                                  3      MATCH
function(1, 2, 3, 4)                               4      MATCH
function(1, function(1, 2), 3)                     3      MATCH
function(function(function(1, 2), 2), 2, 3, 4)     4      MATCH
function(1, 2)                                     2   NO-MATCH
function(1, function(1, function(1, 2)))           2   NO-MATCH
function(1, function(function(1), 2))              2   NO-MATCH
```

---

From the [*comments*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77081425/match-functions-with-more-than-two-arguments-with-regex/77082421#comment135887225_77081425) :

> I have a pandas dataframe with a bunch of expressions like those. I'd
> like to **delete the rows that have functions calls with more than two
> arguments**

Then, you can use [*boolean indexing*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with the same logic used above :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(text.splitlines(), columns=["col"])

# is there at most two arguments ?
mask = [fn(exp).count(",") <= MIN_ARGS-2 for exp in df["col"]]

out = df.loc[mask]
```

Output :

```
print(out)

                                        col
4                            function(1, 2)
5  function(1, function(1, function(1, 2)))
6     function(1, function(function(1), 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach using recursion with `Pypi` regex:

- Definition of "one argument" (referred by `(?2)`):
  a string which contains neither comma nor parentheses,
  or a function call.
  (possible problem: what if the argument looks like `a * (b + c)` ?
  => not considered as of now)

  - expressed by: `([^(),]+|(?3))`
  - then expanded as: `([^(),]+|(\b\w+\s*\((?:([^(),]+|(?3))(?:\s*,\s*(?2))*)*\)))`
- Definition of "arguments":
  comma separated list of 0 or more argument(s) i.e. `(?2)`
  comma may be preceded/followed by 0 or more space(s)

  - expressed by: `(?:(?2)(?:\s*,\s*(?2))*)*`
- Definition of "function call" (referred by `(?3)`):
  function name + 0 or more space(s) + '(' + Arguments + ')'

  - expressed by: `(\b\w+\s*\((?:([^(),]+|(?3))(?:\s*,\s*(?2))*)*\))`

Then the desired pattern, a function with 3 or more arguments, can be
expressed by:
`(\b\w+\s*\(([^(),]+|(\b\w+\s*\((?:([^(),]+|(?3))(?:\s*,\s*(?2))*)*\)))(?:\s*,\s*(?2)){2,}\))`

Code:

```
import regex

str = '''
function(1, 2, 3)
function(1, 2, 3, 4)
function(1, function(1, 2), 3)
function(function(function(1, 2), 2), 2, 3, 4)
function(1, 2)
function(1, function(1, function(1, 2)))
function(1, function(function(1), 2))
'''

pat = r'(\b\w+\s*\(([^(),]+|(\b\w+\s*\((?:([^(),]+|(?3))(?:\s*,\s*(?2))*)*\)))(?:\s*,\s*(?2)){2,}\))'

m = regex.findall(pat, str)
if m:
    print([x[0] for x in m])    # pick 1st element of tuples
```

Output:

```
['function(1, 2, 3)', 'function(1, 2, 3, 4)', 'function(1, function(1, 2), 3)', 'function(function(function(1, 2), 2), 2, 3, 4)']
```